# How to append() value inside the function for python? Why [:] is needed?

Tags: python, append

When using python, as the code shows, when we run the 'print(a)' inside the function. The result is [2,1,3]. However, why the list b is [[1,2,3]] but c is [[2,1,3]].

What's more, if we delete the last sentence of the function (as shown in second part of code), it works well again. It seems .append() runs after the function finishes, why??

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []
c = []
def function():
    a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]

    print(a)

    b.append(a)
    c.append(a[:])
    a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
function()
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

```py
[2,1,3]
[1,2,3]
[[1,2,3]]
[[2,1,3]]
```

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = []
c = []
def function():
    a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]

    print(a)

    b.append(a)
    c.append(a[:])
function()
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

```py
[2,1,3]
[2,1,3]
[[2,1,3]]
[[2,1,3]]
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
b.append(a)
```

appends the variable **a** and

```
c.append(a[:])
```

appends the contents of **a**. In the first case, the variable is appended so a change in the variable **a** changes the value of b since the variable **a** is appended. In the second case, you are just appending **a**'s contents and not the variable. The first is like saying:

```
b = [a]
```

and the second is like saying:

```
c = [2,1,3]
```

Comment: but when we run b=[a], a has been modified to [2,1,3]. If we print list a out, it's [2,1,3]. But when we append(a), b is not [[2,1,3]].

Comment: Appending a and b = [a] should have the same result